# total number of comparisons required by merge sort and selection sort

Tags: mergesort

I am working on a merge sort programme form the scratch web site for  my class pupils using 4 lists each with 10 items but i cannot get it to work correctly I would like to know how many comparisons will selection sort require to sort 4 lists each of length 10?

Answer (score 0):

The number of comparisons depends on the values of the list elements for both sorting methods. Hence there is no fixed number of comparisons for a given list length in the general case. You should implement both sorting methods and count the number of comparisons performed for each list.